# How to send app key in secure way in rest api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, api

I work in restfull api project and
I have this middleware in Laravel and I want to send this key **'AHMADCBETEAM'** from frontend by ajax securely .
I tried  to put it directly in header but the problem when click inspect I can see the key
I want a way to pass it in header

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthKey
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $token=$request->header('APP_kEY');
        if($token!="AHMADCBETEAM")
        return response()->json(["msg"=>"error"],401);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Security keys are kept in the environment file of the application

Comment: Where are you inspecting? In your browser dev pane? Makes sense you can see it there. Much like passwords. Your browser send your passwords to a backend, encryption is done over the secure connection between browser and backend.

Comment: you should not send private key using RESTful API.